# regex to find all the strings between certain patterns

Tags: python, regex

My input string can be one of the following lines:

```
Active App: Coffee (priority 34)

Active App: Hot Bread (priority 20)

Active App: Hot Baked Bread (priority 1)

etc...
```

In this case, instead of "`Coffee`", it could be any string [a-zA-Z] (one or more words).

In "`(priority 34)`", only the integer would change.

So how do I get the "`Coffee`"/"`Hot Bread`"/"`Hot Baked Bread`" from this line?

I am unable to properly handle the space between the words.

Comment: Space between words in regex can be added to the one or more words part: `[a-zA-Z ]`. But I'd suggest to take a look at this module instead: [parse](https://pypi.org/project/parse/). It will make your life easier.

Comment: for at least one space between words you can use /s+

Comment: something like `s.split(': ')[-1].split(' (')[0]
`

Comment: Try `Active App: +([^(]+?) +\(priority +\d+\)`. What you need is in first capturing group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution with python regex `match()` for you:

It disregards the part of the string after the application name that you want to capture. But that could be added, if important.

It will capture untill it sees a `(`, and then later strip the trailing whitespace character from the string.

```py
import re;

myStr = "Active App: Hot Baked Bread (priority 34)";
appStr = re.match("Active App: ([^\(]*)", myStr);
print(appStr.group(1).rstrip());
```

Here's a version that only captures the actual 'Active App' name, without the need to trim the string afterwards. And also checks to see that a match was found before printing it:

```py
import re;

myStr = "Active App: Coffee Some (priority 34)";
appStringMatch = re.match("Active App: (.*)\s\(", myStr);
if appStringMatch:
    print(appStringMatch.group(1));
```